# Is there a SciPy (or similar Python library) method for querying KDTree within a rectangle instead of a circle?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I have a list of 2d points in an array, shape `[m, 2]` where `m` is very, very large. I need to create small "boxes", shape `[n, n]`, where `n` is odd so that the center element of the array is the point I am interested in, and the other elements of the array are the `k = n*n-1` nearest neighbors around that point of interest. Using SciPy, it is a fairly simple endeavor to construct a KDTree from the first array and then grab the closest neighbors to the point I'm interested in withing a certain distance, but sadly those points will construct a circle of points, whereas I need a box.

I'll show a simple example of what I want just so it hopefully makes sense. I'll want `n=3` and I will query the point `[1,2]`

```
array = [[0,0], --> tree = createtree(array) --> tree.query_box([1,2], [3,3]) = [[0,1],
         [0,1],                                                                  [0,2],
         [0,2],                                                                  [0,3],
         [0,3],                                                                  [1,1],
         [1,0],                                                                  [1,2],
         [1,1],                                                                  [1,3],
         [1,2],                                                                  [2,1],
         [1,3],                                                                  [2,2],
         [2,0],                                                                  [2,3]]
         [2,1],
         [2,2],
         [2,3],
         [3,0],
         [3,1],
         [3,2],
         [3,3]]
```

The closest thing I can find is `tree.query_ball_point([1,2],r=3)`, but as I said, those points create a circle not a box.

Comment: In your example, the data appears to be the coordinates of the integer grid points.  Is that what your data really looks like?

Comment: Yeah, I hoping for a more elegant solution, but this is what I am doing for now.

Comment: If your data is really just a regular grid of integers, there should be no need for searching--just compute the indices.  E.g., suppose `n = 3` and `point = [1, 2]`. If I understand correctly, you could do something like `from itertools import product; k = np.arange(-(n-1)//2, (n+1)//2); result = np.array(list(product(point[0]+k, point[1]+k)))`

Comment: (You'll have to adjust the lower and upper bounds passed to `arange` if `point` is close to the edge of the grid.)

Comment: My data is actually a list of longitude and latitude pairs, that I am trying to make robust enough to handle cases where it isn't a regular grid.